# Mixing Datastax Enterprise with Cassandra community

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm experimenting with Datastax Enterprise and I'm trying to have a cluster that mixes Enterprise nodes and standard Cassandra community nodes. I would only need a few nodes with advanced features like Solr and it would be nice to have all the nodes in the same cluster.

I tried to bootstrap a community node to a test Enterprise cluster, and it couldn't join the ring properly, throwing exceptions like that:

```
Unable to find compaction strategy class 
'com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.compaction.CFSCompactionStrategy'
```

I assume that the Enterprise node tries to replicate CFs that have features from DSE, which are not recognized by the community node.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening? Am I trying to do something that's not possible/supported/allowed by DSE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an unsupported configuration. The full cluster needs to be installed with DataStax enterprise binaries on all nodes.  You can choose which nodes run as vanilla Cassandra, Hadoop or Solr by startup options on each node.  DSE has a custom compaction strategy and snitch so that error is expected.